# How to know when a view controller is presented using a 'form sheet' modal presentation style

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

When presenting a view controller modally, we can set the `modalPresentationStyle` to `.formSheet`:

> In a horizontally regular environment, the view controller is sized so that its content area is smaller than the screen size and a dimming view is placed underneath the content...
>
> In a horizontally compact environment, this option behaves the same as UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen.

I would like my modally presented view controller to update its layout based on whether it is being presented in this reduced-width form style, or as a full screen presentation. But The modal's horizontal size class is *always* `compact`, even when full screen on an iPad Pro in landscape.

The horizontal size class of the *presenting* view controller can tell me what I need to know (as Apple's docs mention above). But that means observing changes in traitCollection in every view controller than can present my modal, just so they pass them on to the modal view controller.

Is there some way for the modal view controller itself to know which style it is using, **and** be alerted when it changes so it can respond?

Answer (score 0):

One slightly-gross way to at least know the applications size class:

`UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.traitCollection`